# How to reboot the cisco switch with Netmiko SSH (Python)?

Tags: python, switch-statement, cisco

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco = {
'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
'ip': ip,
'username': username,
'password': password,
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
net_connect.send_command('wr')
net_connect.send_command('reload')
```

CLI on cisco switch after issuing 'reload' command, outputs - "Proceed with reload? [confirm]"

I know I have to handle this output, but I don't know how. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
net_connect.send_command('reload', expect_string='confirm')
net_connect.send_command('\n')
```

I find the solution, but I'm not sure if this is the right way